# Encoding a Web Form in JSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, forms

I have a web form which reads values in from a database and displays them in boxes which I want to eventually allow the user to edit and save.

Currently the user selects the ID of the record and one of the fields works fine, how do I encode this form in JSON to display the entire record when the ID is inserted? Thanks

My current front-end code -

```
 var id=jQuery("#myid").val();
 jQuery.getJSON('find.php',{num:id},function(obj){

if (obj.length>0){ 
 jQuery("input.fname").val(data); 
 jQuery("input.sname").val(data); 
 jQuery("input.age").val(data); 
  } 

});
```

Back - end code -

```
 $id = $_GET['id'];

 $query = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE ID = $id";

 $result = array('FirstName' => 1, 'Surname' => 2, 'Age' => 3);

 echo json_encode($result);
```

Where's my mistake?

Comment: Why encode a form when you can just encode data?

Comment: Ok, I'm open to suggestions, how would I go about that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your frontend, when a user clicks on id(button/anchor) to edit the corresponding record, you can request for a json from backend.

```
var id=$("#recordID").val();  //assuming its an input
$.getJSON('file.php',{num:id},function(obj){

//assign values to your input fields using this obj
$("input.fname").attr("value",obj.FirstName); 
$("input.sname").attr("value",obj.SurName); 
$("input.age").attr("value",obj.Age); 
});
```

In the backend,

```
$id=$_GET['num'];
//select * from yourtable where id=$id

//encode the result array(associative) using json_encode
//echo the json object
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I am close ant I'm trying to print the first three fields of a record as an example.

Comment: and u cannot calculate length of an object..it has no such property..instead u can calculate no of rows returned in backend and encode the result with the other data and use it on client side.

Answer (score 1):

To encode just the data in php you can use:

```
json_encode($data);
```

and to decode them:

```
json_decode($json_data);
```

more reference here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php